# Output capitalized names from randomUser.me api?

Tags: javascript, json, api

Forgive me if this isn't the right platform to ask this question. And let me preface that I'm a designer with very little API and javascript experience.

I'm using the [randomUser](http://randomuser.me) api to generate a json file or url I can input in Invision's Craft tool for Sketch, so I can input real data in my designs. https://screencast.com/t/jAkwUpUja2. However, it gives the names in lowercase instead of title-case/capitalized.

I'm generating the JSON by typing the endpoints I need in the browser: https://screencast.com/t/E8Cmjk5XSSCk

So, is there a way I can force the api to give me capitalized names? Thanks!

EDIT: here is the JSON url: https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20&nat=us&inc=name,gender,picture&format=pretty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at the documentation suggests that there might not be a way to get the API to return capitalized names directly. So you're going to have to write some JavaScript to do the job for you.

This code should print out the data to the console with all names capitalized.

It iterates through the items in the result array, goes through all properties of the item's `name` property and capitalizes them.

The `capitalize` function gets the first character of the name, converts it to upper case and appends it to the rest of the name.

```js
function capitalize(text) {
  return (!text || !text.length) ?
    text :
    (text[0].toUpperCase() + text.slice(1));
}

$.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20&nat=us&inc=name,gender,picture&format=pretty",
  function(data) {
    if (!data || !data.results)
      return;

    data.results.forEach(function(user) {
      if (user.name) {
        for (var name in user.name) {
          user.name[name] = capitalize(user.name[name]);
        }
      }
    });
    console.log(data);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: wow thank you!! Quick question: Can I take this and print out the JSON as a useable url (like the original)? or downloadable json file?

Comment: You could save the content into a text file and name it something.json.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a js noob. Could you show me how to do that? Thank you!

Comment: I tried doing this but it didn't work (I'm using firebase as well): 
https://screencast.com/t/cmFJbWM2Ecdp

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest way to capitalize a string with JS, as far as i know:

```
// let's assume, that you have stored the lastname as follow:
let last = 'rodney';
```

To transform the lastname, you apply this pattern:

```
let capitalizedLast = last[0].toUpperCase() + last.substr(1);
```

`last[0]` returns the first letter of the string `r`.
`last.substr(1)` gives the rest of the lastname `odney`
with `toUpperCase()` you transform the first letter and `+` will concatenate both to the final result.

You just need to itterate over the results from your API and transform the elements that you needed in that way.

Comment: Thanks Steven! So I would have to do this separately/after-the fact? Damn. I honestly wouldn't know where to start with this but I understand what you're doing. If it helps, here is the JSON url: https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20&nat=us&inc=name,gender,picture&format=pretty

Comment: A quick look to the API brings me to this page: https://randomuser.me/documentation#howto 
The best way to start is probably open up a text/code editor, paste the example-code in, open the html-file you've just created in a browser and continuously learning/experimenting (or the simpler way: hire an experienced developer).